# How to read a file in android studio project folder?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am new to android and it seems I cannot get a filepath of a file within the project structure.

I have a text file "db-info.txt", that I am trying to read from a class. Every method I tried has said no file found. This file I am trying to read from a java class within the same folder.

Any help is appreciated. Here is where my file is within the project -
[image: image-showing-file-location-within-project]

Comment: Move it from there to an `app/src/main/assets/` directory. Then, [use `AssetManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager) and `open()` to get an `InputStream` on the asset.